# IOS drawing on an image but my touch gesture cuts off in the middle of movement

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uigesturerecognizer, cgcontext

I am developing some functionality that will let the user "draw" on an image by placing their finger on the screen and moving it around.  I have the following code (taken from the tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit):

```
// Draws a line from point1 to point2
- (void) drawOnImage:(CGPoint *)point1 :(CGPoint *)point2 {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), point1->x, point1->y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), point2->x, point2->y);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}

// Begining of the drawing
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (currentAction == DRAW) {
        [self backupImage];
        mouseSwiped = NO;

        //disable the renderImageView so that the gestures dont interfere


        [self drawOnImage :&lastPoint :&lastPoint];
    }
}

// When lines are being drawn on the image
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (currentAction == DRAW) {
        mouseSwiped = YES;
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)]; // I switched the tempDrawImage to mainImage
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);

        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); // I switched the tempDrawImage to mainImage
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        lastPoint = currentPoint;
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)]; // I switched the tempDrawImage to mainImage
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); // I switched the tempDrawImage to mainImage
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
    if (currentAction == DRAW) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size);
        [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
        [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1]; // I switched the tempDrawImage to mainImage
        self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        //self.tempDrawImage.image = nil;
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    }

}
```

If the screen is being touched very lightly when drawing sometimes the drawing stops. Like midway through a stroke the line stops drawing and in order to start drawing again you have to lift your finger off the screen and press again. This confuses me a great deal because I would think that if the touch gesture was not being recognized for a second then the drawing would stop for a brief second, and when it was recognized again the drawing would continue. This isn't what happens though, you have to lift your finger off the screen and re-apply it. Does anyone have any ideas on what could cause this or have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Using the sample project of the tutorial, the issue seems to be that sometimes the color picker swallows the touch events of the drawing canvas. This tutorial is very dated and some of the techniques are archaic.

Comment: @beyowulf Ah, do you have an example of a non-outdated tutorial or can you point me in the correct direction?